# How do I edit text displayed on my browser tab?

Tags: pages, page-template, html

I want to remove the page name from displaying in my browser's tab. How do I hide the page name and only show the name of my website?

[image]

Comment: that would be the 'meta title', and people tend to use one of the seo plugins to choose what to show.

Comment: @Michael How do I edit the meta title in WordPress for a specific page without a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use this code in your function.php

```
remove_all_filters( 'wp_title' );
add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle', 99,1);
function filter_pagetitle($title) {
    $title = get_bloginfo('name');
    return $title;
}
```

Or install plugin like [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).

---

EDIT : Screenshot

[image]

---

UPDATE : Change header.php in your theme folder if above solution doesn't work for you.

`<title><?php get_bloginfo('name'); ?></title>`

Comment: It didn't work. No change after adding it to functions.php.

Comment: Strange it works for me. 
check if you are using any SEO plugins or not ?

Comment: Try `return ' ';` instead of  `return $title;` and see if it works.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: I don't use any SEO plugins

Comment: Try adding priority to add_filter. Check updated answer

`add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle', 99, 1);`

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57523/discussion-between-jitendra-rana-and-brody-james).

Answer (score 0):

- Setting Site Title in Wordpress: failed
- Editing function.php: not found
- Using All-in-one SEO plugin: failed
- Editing header.php: Worked!

This is what worked for me.  Your mileage may vary.

Please understand that this site does not support HTML, so I've substituted square brackets for angle brackets and '(amp)' for ampersand.

1. Edit the following file:

```
    (your_blog)/wp-content/themes/(your_theme)/header.php
```

2. Find the line:

```
    [meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="[?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?]; charset=[?php bloginfo('charset'); ?]" /]
```

3. Add the following line after the line shown above.  I copied mine from my other WordPress blog that didn't have this problem - (the advantages of dual redundancy).

```
    [title][?php wp_title('(amp)laquo;', true, 'right'); ?] [?php bloginfo('name'); ?][/title]
```

4. Save the file and upload it to the same place on your website.
5. Reload your blog site and hope something else isn't overwriting your site name.